# Django Filter Returning Attribute Errors

Tags: python, django

I have the following code, that is purposed to create a filtered view of my dataset based on a few dropdown selections defined in MyFilter. In my /picks url, I see the search bar but no criteria to filter with. When I navigate to /picks/8 to test the filtering, I get the following attribute with my model. I've also tried orders = Pick.order_set.all() with no luck as well. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

error:

```
'Pick' object has no attribute 'model'
```

pick_list.html:

```
<form method="get">
  {{myFilter.form}}

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def week(request):
    #orders = Pick.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    orders = Pick.objects.all()
    #orders = week.order_set.all()

    myFilter = PickFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders)
    orders = myFilter.qs 

    context = {'week':week, 'orders':orders, 'order_count':order_count,
    'myFilter':myFilter}
    return render(request, 'app/pick_list.html',context)
```

filters.py

```
class PickFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    age = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    name = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')


    class Meta:
        model = Pick
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['photo']
```

models.py

```
class Pick(models.Model):

    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Submitter', null=True, blank=True)
    week = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Week', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name', null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)
    #photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", max_length=500, verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Hometown', null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Age', null=True, blank=True)
    progress = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Progress', null=True, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Occupation', null=True, blank=True)
    elim_week = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Week Eliminated', null=True, blank=True)
    rank = OrderField(verbose_name='Rank', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_from_object(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app:pick-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pick'
        ordering = ['rank']
        verbose_name = 'Pick'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Picks'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('picks/', PickList.as_view(), name='pick-list'),
    path('picks/filter/', week, name="week"),
]
```

error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/picks/filter/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account',
 'cms',
 'app',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django_cleanup',
 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : <!doctype html>
   3 : <html lang="en">
   4 : <head>
   5 :   <meta charset="utf-8">
   6 :   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   7 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
   8 :     integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
   9 :     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
   10 :   


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\app\views.py", line 145, in week
    return render(request, 'app/pick_list.html',context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 698, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\cms\templatetags\cms_tags.py", line 60, in get_verbose_name
    obj._meta.get_field(field), 'verbose_name') else 'name'

Exception Type: AttributeError at /picks/filter/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Isn't `week.order_set` supposed to be a `QuerySet` of `Order`s, not `Pick`s?

Comment: Adjusted my question... removed order_set and tried orders = Pick.objects.get(id=pk_test), which returns the error 'Pick' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: but here `orders` is a *single* `Pick` object: the idea of a filter is to filter a `QuerySet`, so a *collection* of items.

Comment: Ah that explains it well... I'm trying to filter my queryset of Pick objects to just those mentioned in MyFilter - how would I adjust for this?

Comment: you can filter `orders = Pick.objects.all()` for example, but then it is not clear to me what `pk_test` is doing here.

Comment: I can remove pk_test... This was there when I was trying to filter to just a single record for testing (e.g. show me just id=8).

Comment: you will in that case need to use a different path, otherwise you have two `'picks/` and then it will take the first one. But you thus can filter the entire queryset of `Pick`s with the django filter.

Comment: I've adjusted the code above to where I'm at now... I now am getting an error regarding my filter (when navigating to /picks/filter) showing: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'. - any idea why this is causing an issue when i have two fields in my filter, both strings?

Comment: can you edit the question with the full traceback? It also does not make much sense to specify both `fields` and `exclude`, and to set `age` as a `CharFilter` on the `name` field.

Comment: Added the Traceback error in the question

Comment: shouldn't this be `{% endcomment %}` iso `{% endcomm ent %}`.

Comment: Weird, it shows up correctly in my code but differently in the traceback

Comment: Removed the comment line, and received the updated error instead at line 0

Comment: is it possible to work with a small template (create a new one), that only renders the items. This might help debugging whether it is the view, or something in the template that goes wrong.